# When is the projective limit non-empty?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a directed projective system and $S = \varprojlim S_i$.

1.How to prove that $S$ is non-empty in the following case: all $S_i$ are nonempty compact Hausdorff spaces.

2.I know that when $S_i$ are non-empty sets and $f_{ij}$ are surjective, $S$ may still be empty. But if we furthermore assume that $I$ is countable, then $S$ can be shown to be non-empty. What more can we say about the non-emptyness of $S$?

Comment: Why do you think the limit could be empty even if the S_i$ are nonempty and all structure maps are surjective?

Comment: @Anton If $I$ is the set of countable ordinals and $S_\alpha$ is the set of order-embeddings of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, then we have a projective system of epimorphisms between nonempty sets whose limit is empty.

Comment: @Neil Strickland: So if I embed $\omega$ as the natural numbers, then this embedding is the restriction of an embedding of $\omega +1$?

Comment: OK, that's not quite right.  I think I mean embeddings with image bounded above.

Comment: An important criterion in the countable case is: All S_i are non-empty complete metric spaces , the "spectral maps" $f_{i,j}$ are continuous, and they have dense range. This is due to Richard Arens (1958). It appears also in Bourbaki where it is called "Mittag-Leffler condition".

Comment: A minor generalization for (2): $I$ may be countably cofinal, not necessarily countable, to obtain the same conclusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is to supplement Fred Rohrer's answer, copying out some details extracted from Bourbaki (in writing for instance TG.I.9.6, he was referring to a French edition of Topologie Générale, but I'll just refer to the English language edition of Bourbaki's Set Theory Treatise, starting [here](https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-3-642-59309-3/10.1007-978-3-642-59309-3#page/n203/mode/2up), page 205/418).

Suppose given a directed set $D$ (i.e., a partially ordered set such that any two elements have an upper bound), regarded as a category, and suppose given a functor $F: D^{op} \to Set$ whose value at $\alpha \in D$ is denoted $F_\alpha$, with transition maps denoted $f_{\alpha \beta}: F_\beta \to F_\alpha$ when $\alpha < \beta$. Suppose further that for each $\alpha \in D$, one is given a collection of subsets $S_\alpha \subseteq P(F_\alpha)$, each closed under arbitrary intersections [so vacuously $F_\alpha \in S_\alpha$!] and satisfying the finite intersection property. (For example, if the $F_\alpha$ carry compact Hausdorff space structures, we could take $S_\alpha$ to be the collection of closed subsets of $F_\alpha$.) The finite intersection property could be replaced by:

> If $K \subseteq S_\alpha$ is codirected, i.e., has the property that for all $A, B \in K$ there is $C \in K$ with $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$, and if also $\emptyset \notin K$, then $\bigcap K \neq \emptyset$. (**)

**Theorem:** Assume that $f_{\alpha\beta}(C) \in S_\alpha$ whenever $C \in S_\beta$, and that $f^{-1}(x) \in S_\beta$ whenever $x \in F_\alpha$. Then for the projective limit $L$ with universal cone $f_\alpha: L \to F_\alpha$, we have $f_\alpha(L) = \bigcap_{\alpha \leq \beta} f_{\alpha\beta}(F_\beta)$.

Note we have the following corollary.

**Corollary:** Under the assumptions of the theorem, if all the $F_\alpha$ are nonempty, then so is $L$.

This follows from the theorem by choosing any $\alpha \in D$ and taking $K = \{f_{\alpha\beta}(F_\beta): \alpha \leq \beta\}$, noting that $K$ is codirected because $D$ is directed, and applying the highlighted condition (**). (In the exceptional case where $D$ is empty, the projective limit $L$ is the terminal set, hence nonempty.)

Here is an outline of how Bourbaki proves the theorem. First he sets up a Zorn's lemma situation: let $\Sigma$ be the poset whose elements are tuples of the form $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in D}$ such that $A_\alpha \in S_\alpha$ and $A_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ and $f_{\alpha\beta}(A_\beta) \subseteq A_\alpha$ whenever $\alpha \leq \beta$, and with $\Sigma$ partially ordered by  $(A_\alpha) \preceq (B_\alpha)$ if $B_\alpha \subseteq A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in D$. (Note the change of direction.) Using the highlighted form of the finite intersection property, he notes that every chain in $(\Sigma, \preceq)$ has an upper bound. Thus $\Sigma$ has a maximal element, by Zorn's lemma.

He next shows that if $(A_\alpha)$ is maximal, then $f_{\alpha\beta}(A_\beta) = A_\alpha$. In effect he considers $A_{\alpha}' := \bigcap_{\alpha \leq \beta} f_{\alpha\beta}(A_\beta)$ and checks that $(A_{\alpha}')$ satisfies the requirements for belonging to $\Sigma$ and that $f_{\alpha\beta}(A_{\beta}') = A_{\alpha}'$. Then observe $A_{\alpha}' \subseteq A_\alpha$, so $A_{\alpha}' = A_\alpha$ by maximality of $(A_\alpha)$.

Next he shows that each $A_\alpha$ is a singleton. Hold fixed an $\alpha$, select $x_\alpha \in A_\alpha$, and put $B_\beta := A_\beta \cap f^{-1}_{\alpha\beta}(x_\alpha)$ if $\alpha \leq \beta$; otherwise put $B_\beta = A_\beta$. Bourbaki shows that $(B_\beta)_{\beta \in D}$ belongs to $\Sigma$, and clearly $B_\beta \subseteq A_\beta$ for all $\beta \in D$, so $A_\beta = B_\beta$ for all $\beta$ by maximality of $(A_\beta)$, and in particular $A_\alpha = B_\alpha = \{x_\alpha\}$.

Finally, he shows $f_\alpha(L) = \bigcap_{\alpha \leq \beta} f_{\alpha\beta}(F_\beta)$. The direction $\subseteq$ is immediate. For the other direction, suppose $x_\alpha \in \bigcap_{\alpha \leq \beta} f_{\alpha\beta}(F_\beta)$, and put $B_\beta := f_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}(x_\alpha)$ if $\alpha \leq \beta$, else put $B_\beta = F_\beta$. One argues that $(B_\beta)_{\beta \in D}$ belongs to $\Sigma$ and that there is a maximal element $(A_\beta)$ that is $\preceq$-above $(B_\beta)$, with $A_\beta = \{y_\beta\}$. The tuple $y = (y_\beta)_{\beta \in D}$ belong to the limit $L$, and $f_\alpha(y) = y_\alpha = x_\alpha$, as was to be shown. $\Box$

As for question 2. of the OP, there is the slightly more general statement that if the directed set $D$ admits a countable cofinal subset and all the $f_{\alpha\beta}$ are surjective, then the limit is nonempty (this is without all the extra baggage of the $S_\alpha$ above). The countable cofinal set allows us to reduce to the case $D = \mathbb{N}$ without loss of generality, and then from there it's an easy application of dependent choice. See Proposition 5 in Bourbaki, just before the theorem we quoted above.

Comment: I think the argument is unnecessarily complicated. The product space $\prod_\alpha F \alpha$ is compact Hausdorff by Tychonoff's theorem. The limit $\varprojlim_\alpha F\alpha \subseteq \prod_\alpha F\alpha$ is the intersection of a family of nonempty closed subspaces which has the finite intersection property by hypothesis (i.e. the family $X_{\alpha\beta} = \{(x_i)_i \mid x_\beta = f_{\alpha\beta}(x_\alpha)\}$, ranging over all $\alpha \geq \beta$). So it is nonempty, too. But perhaps this statement could be used to provide an alternative proof of Tychonoff's theorem in the Hausdorff case.

Comment: @TimCampion If this were only a comment on the OP's 1., then yes, I believe you're right. The first sentence explains what this answer really is. It is of independent interest anyway to know also precise conditions for nonemptyness for the category $Set$ (see e.g. Neil's comment for what can go wrong).

Comment: Yes, I was only referring to (1). I'm actually delighted to learn of Neil's example!

Answer (score 3):

1. A proof is given in Bourbaki's TG.I.9.6.
2. General conditions for a projective limit in the category of sets to be nonempty are given in Bourbaki's E.III.7.4.

Comment: This would be a much more useful answer if you could include at least a sketch of the proof and state the conditions.

Comment: Well, Bourbaki's treatise is a standard reference one should always have at reach, and thus it is certainly not necessary to copy such things here.

Comment: I feel that @FredRohrer's answer was perfect. Actually, I've voted to close the Question.

Comment: I agree with Mike. Bourbaki is probably not "within reach" (i.e., not in one's personal library) for most people, and may or may not be in a local university library which in turn may or may not be nearby. If you have Bourbaki at reach, then it would be a nice public service if you or someone else would flesh out this answer.

Comment: Bourbaki is certainly not within my reach.  In most respects it has been superseded by newer references, so I don't think it is reasonable to expect all mathematicians to have it at hand.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't matter how "standard" a reference is; it is *always* more useful to actually give an answer than to simply point to where an answer can be found.  For instance, http://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer says "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."  Surely that suggestion applies at least as strongly to a citation of an offline resource!

Comment: @FredRohrer Well, though I'd prefer a sketch of proof, but thanks very much for pointing out the reference!